# updating to xcode6 messed up my apps coredata

Tags: xcode, core-data

So I made the huge mistake of updating to xCode 6. I opened the project I was working on (objc not swift) and there are suddenly tons of errors where there weren't any before the update.

Why is this

```
 fetchedObjects = [[[NSApp delegate] managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];
```

now giving me the error:

```
no known instance method for selector 'managedObjectContext'
```

PLEASE HELP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try casting `[NSApp delegate]` to whatever class implements `managedObjectContext`, and including its header (if you don't already do that).